# How to define the sum with conditions over rows?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `A` and a list `N`.

```
> dput(N)
list(`1` = 2L, `2` = c(1L, 3L, 4L), `3` = c(1L, 2L, 4L), `4` = 1:3)
```

I need to set the matrix `P` by:

[image],
where `|N_i|` means the number of elements in the set `N_i`.

My attempt is:

```
n <- 4

A <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0), n, n, byrow = TRUE)
for(i in N[i])
for(j in N[j]){
         if(i!=j){
                 sum1 = sum1 + A[i,j]
                 sum2 = sum2 + A[j,i]
                 }
}
```

**Question:** How to define the sum with conditions over rows?

Comment: at the point `for(i in N[i])` the `i` is undefined

Comment: it would be helpful with a bit more clarification of what you're trying to do (your code and the equation are a bit of a mismatch?) and what the expected result is in a case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
P=matrix(NA,n,n)

for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:n){
    if(i!=j){
      P[i,j]=0.5*(sum(A[N[[i]],j])/length(N[[i]])+sum(A[N[[j]],i])/length(N[[j]]))
    }
  }
}
```

resulting in

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]        NA 0.1666667 0.6666667 0.5000000
[2,] 0.1666667        NA 0.3333333 0.5000000
[3,] 0.6666667 0.3333333        NA 0.6666667
[4,] 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.6666667        NA
```

Comment: |N_i| means the number of elements in the set.

Comment: @Nick Corrected.